# Mapbox's Static Tiles API rendering error at endpoint / join of road-path "X" marks

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I have tried to create a custom map style in mapbox studio based on the outdoor style. In the normal preview everything looks fine. If I switch to settings --> debug tools --> activate static tiles I got a lot of "x" marks at the endpoints or joins of roads, trail and path.

I didn't find a setting that could change this behaviour and I can't see a system which combination (path-road, endpoint ...) trigger this behavouir.

At zoom level 15-16 the marks disappear.

At stackoverflow is a recent post that describes exactly my problem:
[how-to-remove-x-mark-from-staticmap-images-made-by-mapboxs-static-tile-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78032310/how-to-remove-x-mark-from-staticmap-images-made-by-mapboxs-static-tile-api)

If I load the map as WMTS in brwoser / arcgis-pro / qgis I get the same errors.

**Normal preview:**
[image]

**Preview with static tiles enabled**
[image]